# C# Looping through two lists, removing duplicates from list #2

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have an array of file names (aryFileNames) of a directory.  I have a list of file names (lstKeepers) from a CSV file.  This list is a listing of the files that are SUPPOSED to be in the directory.  What I'm essentially doing is looking for orphan files in the directory.

I have redone this logic 3 times now and every time I eventually hit a bump that has me needing to rework it, so I'm just going to ask flat out how I should handle this.

My current logic is this:

```
List<string> lstKeepers = new List<string>(aryKeepers);
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(txtMSALoc.Text);
FileInfo[] attFiles = dir.GetFiles();
//variable for testing if a keeper was found.
bool bolTest = false;
//Loop through the directory's files
foreach (FileInfo attFile in attFiles)
{
    //Loop through the list of keepers
    foreach (string lstKeeper in lstKeepers){
        if (lstKeeper == attFile.Name)
        {
            //This file is a keeper not an orphan, remove it from the list.
            // This line doesn't actually work.  Is a List the right way to go?
            lstKeepers(lstKeeper).remove;
            bolTest = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // Code fell out of the loop, see if it found a keeper.
    if (bolTest)
    {
        bolTest=false;
    }
    else
    {
        //CODE TO MOVE FILE INTO ORPHAN DIRECTORY
    }
}
```

I'm dealing with potential directories (and keeper lists) of up to 2 million files, so that's the reason I want to keep shrinking the keeper list with every file it finds, so things should go faster the longer it runs.

So my first question is, is there a better way of doing this?

My next question is, are arrays and lists the best things to use?  I saw something about linkedlist being better when you need to remove stuff.

Here's briefly what I tried before:

1) Looping through the directory list and keeper list at the same time:
As both are numeric values for the most part file.name = 123, file.name = 124 and so on, I was just comparing the values of the file names and determining actions to take based on whether the current pair was < or > each other or =.  But because of lack of natural sorting this didn't work.

2) Using just two arrays, but removing items from an array isn't practical (as I'd have to keep recreating the array).

3) (current) this seemed the way to go as I could remove items but then someone said to use LinkedLists for removing items and because I'm tired of restarting this project, that was the straw that broke the coder's back :)

Any advice is appreciated!

UPDATE:  This is the final version, thanks much to everyone for your help!

```
            string[] aryKeepers;
            if (File.Exists("Keepers.csv"))
            {
                aryKeepers = File.ReadAllLines("Keepers.csv");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot find 'Keepers.csv' file.", "Missing CSV File Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                aryKeepers = null;
                return;
            }
            List<string> lstKeepers = new List<string>(aryKeepers);
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(txtMSALoc.Text);
            FileInfo[] attFiles = dir.GetFiles();
            List<string> lstOrphans = attFiles
                                        .Where(x => !lstKeepers.Contains(x.Name))
                                        .Select(x => x.Name)
                                        .ToList();
            if (lstOrphans.Count > 0){
                intOrphan = lstOrphans.Count;
                lstOrphans.ForEach (lstOrphan => {
                    string strOldFile = txtMSALoc.Text + @"\" + lstOrphan;
                    string strNewFile = dirOrphan + lstOrphan;
                    File.Move(strOldFile, strNewFile);
                });
            }
```

Comment: What is `lstKeepers`? A `List<string>`?

Comment: Why not check for case sensitivity? for example instead of (lstKeeper == attFile.Name), try using something like (lstKeeper.Tolower() == attFile.Name.Tolower())

Comment: You could build a second temp list of all of the items that are not "Removed" from the keeper list, then at the end of the loop just replace your keeper list with the temp one. Could be easier then trying to remove items.

Comment: @gunr2171: Updated the code with the array and list declarations.

Comment: @Consult Yarla: All filenames numeric values, so case is not an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just

```
List<string> orphans = new List<string>();

// Enumerate files in directory
foreach(string file in attFiles)
{
    // If the filename isn't in the keepers list it must be 
    // an orphan, add it to the orphans list
    if(!lstKeepers.Contains(file.Name))
        orphans.Add(file.Name);
}
```

Then afterwards

```
foreach(string orphanedFile in orphans)
{ 
    // Move the file
}
```

I don't think it will be amazingly performant but you didn't mention performance issues - just that you couldn't get the logic right

I might also add that trying to remove items from a list whilst enumerating it (i.e. the `foreach` loop) will cause a runtime exception, which might be one of the issues you are encountering

**Edit:** Just for fun and because everyone loves linq (and because gunr2171 suggested it)

```
List<string> orphans = attFiles
                            .Where(x => !lstKeepers.Contains(x.Name))
                            .Select(x => x.Name)
                            .ToList();
```

Then you could

```
orphans.ForEach(orphan => { // Do something });
```

Comment: For the first code block, if you want, `orphans = attFiles.Where(x => !lstKeepers.Contains(x.Name)).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();`

Comment: I could try that certainly.  Does array have the Contains method?  If so is array or list better to use?  I am certainly concerned with performance, so will this be any slower than looping through the list manually?

Comment: @CharlesBHamlyn // why don't you look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be(v=vs.110).aspx maybe Arrat.Exists<T> method is what you are looking for :)

Comment: I believe it does http://www.dotnettoad.com/index.php?/archives/10-Array.Contains.html - also behind .NET list types I believe the implementations call `GetHashCode` on all objects (strings included) to do quick comparison - if the hash codes match, then the framework will do an in depth comparison, so I'd try this out before you question performance and see how it does. Worst case if you need to you can call `ToList()` on the array to enumerate it to a list, but I'm sure this works out the box (at least in FX 3.5 with Linqs `Contains` extension)

Comment: And depending on what version of .Net and how powerful your machine is, if you want to minimize perf issues you could even run the move script in parallel: `orphans.AsParallel().ForAll(orphan => {});`

Comment: Combined `AsParallel` with `HashSet` as the other answers specify you could be done before you know it!

Answer (score 3):

You can put the file names in a `HashSet<string>` for fast lookup, then just loop through the files that are found there:

```
FileInfo[] attFiles = new DirectoryInfo(txtMSALoc.Text).GetFiles();
HashSet<string> att = new HashSet<string>(attFiles.Select(a => a.Name));
foreach (string attFile in aryKeepers.Where(s => att.Contains(s))) {
  //CODE TO MOVE FILE INTO ORPHAN DIRECTORY
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a list you could use a `HashSet` as it will give you [O(1) performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Contains` vs O(n) performance with a `List<T>`. The `Remove` performance is also very good so your code could be simplified to:

```
HashSet<string> lstKeepers = new HashSet<string>(aryKeepers);
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(txtMSALoc.Text);
FileInfo[] attFiles = dir.GetFiles();

//Loop through the directory's files
foreach (FileInfo attFile in attFiles)
{
    if (lstKeepers.Contains(attFile.Name))
    {
        //CODE TO MOVE FILE INTO ORPHAN DIRECTORY

        //remove from the HashSet
        lstKeepers.Remove(attFile.Name);
    }
}
```